# Problem installing LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I followed the instructions for installing LibreOffice found [here](http://drupal.txwikinger.me.uk/content/libreoffice-now-available-ppa-ubuntu-1010-and-1004), which are basically the same instructions found all over askubuntu and the web in general.

I followed the instructions (including removing OO first) for gnome; all that is in my Applications menu now is LibreOffice (OO used to have OpenOffice Spreadsheet, OpenOffice Presentation, etc.) When I open LibreOffice, I get the splash screen/menu, but all of the choices for creating new docs are greyed out.

[image]

It also will not open any office/type files (no errors; they just don't open.) The terminal commands indicated that installation was successful, but obviously something is missing. I'm guessing I can just reinstall OO from the software center, but I'd really like to give LibreOffice a try, given the lack of ongoing development on OO. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: if you have no extensions installed, try removing your ~/.LibreOffice and ~/.OpenOffice folders as well. If that doesn't work try reinstalling. Btw, check in synaptic and ensure that all the libreoffice packages are installed - I have a gut feeling that only the core got installed somehow O.o

Comment: Checked synaptic; the following packages are installed: libreoffice-core, libreoffice-common, libreoffice-gnome, libreoffice-style-galaxy, libreoffice-gtk, uno-libs3, ure.

Comment: I installed all the application-specific packages via synaptec; if you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it accepted since you posted before rafalcieslak.

Comment: I had the same issue after the Ubuntu automatic update process: I did not ask for LibreOffice to be set up but it was done anyway. No way to pass through the splash screen. No way to open any document. Annoying bug deh!

I confirm only the libreoffice core component was installed.

I therefore installed any component with 'libreoffice' in it.
Still some problems opening DOC documents but at least I can open something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no extensions installed, try removing your ~/.LibreOffice and ~/.OpenOffice folders as well. If that doesn't work try reinstalling.

Btw, check in synaptic and ensure that all the libreoffice packages are installed - I have a gut feeling that only the core got installed somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have installed the suite, but not all the apps included (Writer, Impress etc.). Try the following:

> sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw libreoffice-math libreoffice-impress libreoffice-base